# Laravel eager loading with nested relationship

Tags: laravel, eager-loading

I know this question has been asked but my situation is different. 
I have Post model with relationship to Comment model defined:

```
/*Post Model*/
public function comments(){
return $this->hasMany('comment');
}
```

and Comment model which each comment belong to one user : 
/*comment model*/

```
public function user(){
return $this->belongto('user');
}
```

now I want to query all post and eager load comments (of each post) along with user information who post the comment. 
anyway to make it work please ? 
thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is nested [eager loading](http://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading), scroll down a bit and you will see it.

Quoting the docs:

> To eager load nested relationships, you may use "dot" syntax. For
>   example, let's eager load all of the book's authors and all of the
>   author's personal contacts in one Eloquent statement:

```
$books = Book::with('author.contacts')->get();
```

In your case

```
$posts = Post::with('comments.user')->get();
```